# Take the ID of an Table after Select Query in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, exception

How can I take the ID as a variable from the Select query in c#.
I have written a query which has to select all IDs with a specific Devicetype.

```
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id FROM T_Table1 WHERE DeviceType='" + dev + "'" + "", DbConnect());

                int id = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

That's the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in test.exe
>
> Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: if that worked you'd only get the first id, not all of them. You may want ExecuteReader instead.

Comment: if database type is bigint use c# long, not int.

Comment: Thanks @Crowcoder. It worked.
long id = (long)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to check the database type of your 'id' column. If it is bigint, then use `long` instead of `int`.

And secondary you should not add the query string to the select statement. That enables hackers later to run a sql injection against your app or service.

Please use Parameters with the SqlCommand object.

```
string sql= "SELECT Id FROM T_Table1 WHERE DeviceType=@dev";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, DbConnect());
command.Parameters.Add("@dev", SqlDbType.Text);
command.Parameters["@dev"].Value = dev;

long id = (long)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Do you know the structure of the table? ID can be of type long, int, ...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int id =Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling Execute scalar which will return the first value of the first column of the returned datarow IIRC... So you are trying to take the integer value of null, which others have stated, cannot occur.

I would suggest using the ExecuteEnumerable flavor to return a set of Datarows containing your ID's from T_Table1

```
using (var myCommand = new SqlCommand()) 
    {
        var query = string.Format("SELECT ID FROM T_Table1 WHERE DeviceType='{0}'", dev);
         var rows = myCommand.ExecuteEnumerable(query);
         foreach (var row in rows) 
            {
             // do whatever to each row
             var id = row["ID"];
            }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If the `SELECT` query finds no matching value in the database, then the return value of `sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` will be `null`, if I rembember correctly. And null value cannot be cast to `int`. You need to check the returned value first before doing the cast. Additionally, you might want to change the type to `long` instead of `int`, because an `int` cannot hold all possible bigint values.

Comment: At whoever downvoted this: Would you please care to explain what is wrong with that answer so that I can fix it?